# How can I implement this in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have string list as below,

```py
flag_list = ['-Werror=unused-but-set-variable', '-Wall', '-D FIRMWARE_MAJOR_VERSON=0', '-D FIRMWARE_MINOR_VERSION=1', '-D _TASK_STD_FUNCTION', '-D DEBUG_ENABLE=1', '-D
ENABLE_DEBUG_MAIN=1', '-D ENABLE_DEBUG_OLED_UI=1', '-D ENABLE_TEST_FEATURES=1', '-D LED=1', '-DSERIAL_NUMBER=1234', '-DREQUIRESNEW']
```

I am trying to implement a function that helps me get the value of the defined flag if available.

Here is what I have tried, I am sure that this is not optimal way of doing this.

```py
def get_flag_value(flags_list, flag_name):
    flag = [s for s in flags if flag_name + "=" in s]
    flag_new = filter(lambda str: str.startswith("-D"), flag)
    print flag_new
    if (len(flag) == 1) :
        print flag_name + " found."
        print flag
        # TODO: Check for the = sign.
        # TODO: get value of parameter if available.
        # return (result, value)
    elif (len(flag) > 1) :
        print "Multiple enteries found"
        print flag
        return (false, 0)
    else:
        print flag_name + " not found"
        return (false, 0)
```

please note that sometimes `-D` may not have the tailing space all the time.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you want and what you have tried?

Comment: Use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), define the parser and pass the list to `parse_args()` method.

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, you should probably ignore Python 2, and concentrate on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: Actually, this is for the `platfomio-core` pre-build script. `PlatformIO` uses python 2.7  So, I can not use python 3 for this.

However, I am Embedded System Developer so my python knowledge is very limited.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @Sandiep follow Giacomo's suggestion, argparse, though a bit daunting at first, does all the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a code. You can try it.

**Code:**

```
input_list = [
    "-Werror=unused-but-set-variable",
    "-Wall",
    "-D FIRMWARE_MAJOR_VERSON=0",
    "-D FIRMWARE_MINOR_VERSION=1",
    "-D _TASK_STD_FUNCTION",
    "-D DEBUG_ENABLE=1",
    "-D ENABLE_DEBUG_MAIN=1",
    "-D ENABLE_DEBUG_OLED_UI=1",
    "-D ENABLE_TEST_FEATURES=1",
    "-D LED=1",
    "-DSERIAL_NUMBER=1234",
    "-DREQUIRESNEW",
]


def get_flag_value(flag_name):
    for item in input_list:
        if flag_name in item:
            return True, item.split("=")[-1]
    return False, False


print(get_flag_value("ENABLE_DEBUG_OLED_UI"))
print(get_flag_value("SERIAL_NUMBER"))
print(get_flag_value("Wall"))
print(get_flag_value("Werror"))
print(get_flag_value("Fake_flag"))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
(True, '1')
(True, '1234')
(True, '-Wall')
(True, 'unused-but-set-variable')
(False, False)
```

**EDIT:**

Make the function to more robust.

**Code:**

```
def get_flag_value(flag_name):
    for item in input_list:
        item = item.replace("-D", "").strip()
        if flag_name.lower() == item.split("=")[0].lower():
            return True, item.split("=")[-1]
    return False, False


print(get_flag_value("ENABLE_DEBUG_OLED_UI"))
print(get_flag_value("SERIAL_NUMBER"))
print(get_flag_value("-Wall"))
print(get_flag_value("-Werror"))
print(get_flag_value("Fake_flag"))
print(get_flag_value("LED"))
print(get_flag_value("REQUIRESNEW"))
```

Output:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
(True, '1')
(True, '1234')
(True, '-Wall')
(True, 'unused-but-set-variable')
(False, False)
(True, '1')
(True, 'REQUIRESNEW')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This only fails for `print(get_flag_value("LED"))` because it matches first with `ENABLE_DEBUG_OLED_UI`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my fault. I have edited my answer and make the function more robust.